# get encoded categorical variables in one row rather than multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have original data frame similar to this

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'uid': [4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 6, 1],'days': ['D1', 'D3', 'D3', 'D4', 'D4', 'D2','D2']})

  uid   days
0   4   D1
1   3   D3
2   6   D3
3   4   D4
4   3   D4
```

I used get_dummies() and got this sort of coded dataframe.

```
my_new_df = pd.get_dummies(my_df ,columns=['days'])

uid days_D1 days_D2 days_D3 days_D4
0   4   1   0   0   0
1   3   0   0   1   0
2   6   0   0   1   0
3   4   0   0   0   1
4   3   0   0   0   1
```

I want a dataframe where all my categorical values are coded in one row for each uid. like this

```
uid D1 D2 D3 D4
4    1  0  0 1
3    0  0  1 1
6    0  1  1 0
1    0  1  0 0
```

I have tried looking for an optimized way of achieving this result but I am unable to that. my original data frame has 222000 values in it. please suggest ways of get encoded categorical variables like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try grouping on the `uid` and get max of other columns after `get_dummies`

```
(pd.get_dummies(my_df ,columns=['days'],prefix='',prefix_sep='')
   .groupby('uid',sort=False).max())
```

Or and alternative with pivot :

```
my_df.pivot_table(index="uid",columns="days",aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)
```

---

```
     D1  D2  D3  D4
uid                
4     1   0   0   1
3     0   0   1   1
6     0   1   1   0
1     0   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this option:

```
ss = pd.get_dummies(my_df, columns=['days']).groupby(['uid'], as_index=False).sum()
print(ss)
```

output:

```
    uid days_D1 days_D2 days_D3 days_D4
0   1     0       1        0       0
1   3     0       0        1       1
2   4     1       0        0       1
3   6     0       1        1       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crosstab` + `clip`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(my_df['uid'], my_df['days']).clip(upper=1)
```

---

```
days  D1  D2  D3  D4
uid                 
1      0   1   0   0
3      0   0   1   1
4      1   0   0   1
6      0   1   1   0
```